# Return a SELECT match where two rows match with different column values

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table with the following columns

```
drug_id | image_filename | cat_id | desc_id | drug_name 
--------|----------------|--------|---------|--------
   3        picx.jpg         3         6       bla1
   3        picy.jpg         3         6       bla2  <
   3        picy.jpg         5         3       bla2  <  match!
   3        picz.jpg         3         6       bla2
   5        pixx.jpg         5         3       bla3
```

I need a query that returns all the unique drug_name where the drug_id is the same, the image_filename matches, AND cat_id=3 AND desc_id=6 AND cat_id=5 AND desc_id=3.

In other words, I need some GROUP BY logic with a `count(*)=2` but since I need certain column conditions to be different for the match, whatever I try isn't working.

Right now, Im returning all the sorted rows and using seq logic and counters to check the conditions and all that nonsense, and I'm really hoping to find a query that can do it all in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way is to use aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select drug_name, drug_id, image_filename
from t
group by drug_name, drug_id, image_filename
having sum(cat_id = 3 and desc_id = 6) > 0 and
       sum(cat_id = 5 and desc_id = 5) > 0;
```

Each condition in the having clause checks that one of the combination of values is present.

Comment: this seems to be working SUPER well...thanks so much for pointing me in this direction!